# a gap in the proof of statement 3.2.8 in Robinson's book

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Could anyone help me with this questions:
Find and correct the gap on the proof of the statement 2.3.8 in Robinson's book

> 3.2.8. Let F be a field and let N be a normal subgroup of SL(n, F) which is not contained in the centre. If either n > 2 or n = 2 and |F|> 3, then N = SL(n, F).

I think on the first part of the proof N contains the commutator $[A,1+E_{1_2}]$ instead of $[A,1+E_{1,n_1+n_2}]$.
[proof of 3.2.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imrR8.png)